# Windows Service restarts on Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, timeout, system.net.webexception

I'm building a windows service that grabs information from a website periodically
How can I start looking again when a exception is caught? for example when internet goes down and up later.

#### Code:

```
public string cadena(string pagina)
        {
            try
            {
                String cadena;
                WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(pagina);
                myWebrequest = 10000;
                WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
                Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
                Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
                StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);
                cadena = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                readStream.Close();
                myWebResponse.Close();
                return cadena;
            }
            catch (WebException error)
            {
                myTimer.Enabled = true;
                return "error";
            }
        }
public void inicia(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
                myTimer.Enabled = false;
                String strSite = cadena("www.something.com");
                //Do something with strSite...
                myTimer.Enabled = true;            
        }
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {           
                    myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();                    
                    myTimer.Interval = 1500;         
                    myTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(inicia);      
                    myTimer.Enabled = true;            
            }
```

Comment: Why not just increase the timer in the catch block and set it to 1500 inside the try?  On the next successful attempt it will have an interval of 1500.  I think you need to catch more than just WebException though, TimeoutException is a big one.

Comment: How can I add another Exception to the catch?

Comment: @unknown: You just chain them up: try {} catch (WebException we){} catch (TimeoutException te){} etc.

Comment: Just add another catch block underneath the first catch block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very crude example to get you started, this will keep your program from continuing until you get a valid response.  There are better ways of doing this, but this is the idea you want.  Good luck!

```
myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
while (myWebResponse.ContentLength == -1) {  
  //sleep
 myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
}  

//continue execution
```

You should probably put in a check to see if the remote site is available, and either poll until it is, or interrupt when the service is available.  This way you won't have to recover from a thrown exception.

I think using exceptions should be reserved for things a little more catastrophic to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried this, but in the middle of the poll if the internet goes out, still hangs there and throw an exception.

Comment: Hrm, I bet that has something to do with the command you try when polling, can you post that code so we can take a look at it?

Comment: Well the function cadena only returns the string with the data, and I get the information I need from the string, so the polling consist in assign the value to the string.

Comment: by the time you check to see if cadena() returns a string, it is too late and your exception has already been thrown.  You need to poll for a valid connection before you start trying to read from your remote site.

Comment: that make sense, what could be the best way to valid the connection in this case?

Comment: I posted an example to get you started, also, can you post the exception you are getting?

Comment: Thnx for the code, the solution worked but now the problem is that some sites return -1 for ContentLength.